# Does the html 'select' keyword work in Awesomium?

Tags: awesomium

I'm using the Awesomium .NET Winforms web browser control and am having some trouble using the 'select' keyword.

The html that demonstrates the behavior is below but first here are a couple of snapshots.

Upon loading the page this picture shows the initial state.

[image: When the page opens]

After clicking on the arrow the control is highlighted but the 'dropdown' does not 'open'.

When the control is highlighted I can use the up and down arrows to change the selection.

[image: Changed with down arrow]

The pages being tested are far more complex and everything except the simple select feature works quite well.  We have a lot of JS going on with no problems at all.

Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the html for the simple page shown above:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Select test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
    <select id="test1">
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known 'feature'.  The popup menu is left to the developer to implement.

"Ken Walker" has very nicely offered up code to perform this action [here](http://forums.awesomium.com/viewtopic.php?p=1024#p1024)

Edit: Unfortunately the link has been removed.  Perhaps this is due to the new version having been released which now has support for this html construct.  I haven't had time to play with the 3/6/13 release yet so I'll post my code here until I see if the update works.

I created a ListBox using the designer called lbSelect.  One thing I have been unable to find is how the Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_ShowPopupMenu is called.  I do not have a hook and I don't see one in the control's properties, however, it is in the designer file and is connected.

One thing to note, you have to select an item in the menu - you cannot select the arrow and make the box go away.  Hopefully the updated Awesomium works and all this code goes away.

```
    private void lbSelect_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            itemSelected = lbSelect.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
    private void Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_ShowPopupMenu(object sender, PopupMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        int count;
        Rectangle lbb = new Rectangle();

        itemSelected = -1;
        lbSelect.Items.Clear();
        count = e.Info.Items.Count;
        lbb.X = e.Info.Bounds.X;
        lbb.Y = e.Info.Bounds.Y + e.Info.Bounds.Height;
        lbb.Height = e.Info.ItemHeight * count;
        lbb.Width = e.Info.Bounds.Width;

        lbSelect.Bounds = lbb;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            lbSelect.Items.Add(e.Info.Items[i].Label);
        }
        lbSelect.Visible = true;
        lbSelect.BringToFront();
        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while (itemSelected == -1);
        e.Info.Select(itemSelected);
        lbSelect.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: H, unfortunately this link is not working anymore. Would you please send me the code for making custom dropdown ?

Comment: Barun, version 1.7.0.5 (3/6/2013) does not support the HTML 'select' keyword in the Winforms version of the Awesomium package.  WPF is supported if you are using that.

The code above and this link should help you - http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_ShowPopupMenu

Comment: Dont worry about it. I have moved to geckoFx-18. Its better than Awesomium in every way.

Comment: Roger.  I tried that a little while ago but it didn't work with our javascript libraries for some reason.  Maybe I'll try it again.

Comment: Btw I have found the Awesomium 1.6.6 version. Now everything is working for Awesomium.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for version 1.7 ...thanks for help...

```
    private ListBox lbSelect;
    private WebControl browser;

    private void CreateBrowser()
    {
        browser = new WebControl();
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        browser.ShowPopupMenu += new ShowPopupMenuEventHandler(browser_ShowPopupMenu);

        lbSelect = new ListBox();
        this.Controls.Add(lbSelect);
        lbSelect.BringToFront();
        lbSelect.Visible=false;
        lbSelect.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(lbSelect_MouseClick);
        lbSelect.LostFocus += new EventHandler(lbSelect_LostFocus);
    }

    private PopupMenuEventArgs _MenuArgs;
    void browser_ShowPopupMenu(object sender, PopupMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        lbSelect.Items.Clear();
        uint count = e.Info.Count;
        for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++)
            lbSelect.Items.Add(e.Info[i].Label);

        Rectangle lbb = new Rectangle
        {
            X = e.Info.Bounds.X,
            Y = e.Info.Bounds.Y + e.Info.Bounds.Height,
            Height = (count <= 10 ? (int)(e.Info.ItemHeight * count) : e.Info.ItemHeight * 10),
            Width = e.Info.Bounds.Width
        };

        lbSelect.Bounds = lbb;
        lbSelect.Visible = true;
        lbSelect.SelectedIndex = e.Info.SelectedItem;
        lbSelect.Focus();

        _MenuArgs = e;
    }

    void lbSelect_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _MenuArgs.Info.Select(lbSelect.SelectedIndex);
        lbSelect.Visible = false;
    }

    void lbSelect_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbSelect.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Barun, this is nice and clean code however, I am unable to get it to work.  I found a couple of things that caused it not to compile: (uint count = had to be e.Info.'Items'.Count and lbSelect.Items.Add had to be (e.Info.Items[i].Label).  Lastly, I get a run-time error when the lbSelect_MouseClick is called.  It says the _ShowPopupMenu has been cancelled so I'm guessing that it is having trouble making the assignment on the first line.

I'm in the process of threading Ken's code so the 'do {} while' goes away.

Comment: Sorry I dont know what happen there. But I am using latest Awesomium and this is my compiled code.

Comment: I guess they have changed a lot at this current version. Now 'Info' is also a enumerable object. By the way I need a little help. Do you know how get images from Awesomium WebControl page ?

Comment: @CramerTV - Hello again, I need a little help from you. It seems the new version is good for nothing. Do you have the previous version of Awesomium ? I mean version 1.6.4 or 1.6.6 ? If you have it would you please send it to me ? I will really appreciate it. My email aiorginal@gmail.com ....... Thanks in advance

Comment: Barun, the oldest package I have is 1.7 rc3.  The date shows January 18th, 2013 but I don't know if that's when they released it or when I installed it.  If you'd like that one let me know.

FWIW, the new one seems to be working well for me but I'm only using it for fairly simple web pages - there's no imagery, audio or video content for example.

Answer (score 0):

Predefined drop-down (popup) menus will be available for both the WPF and the WinForms `WebControl`, in the final release of version 1.7.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not

Comment: For WPF, they were there. And for the WinForms `WebControl`, they are added in **v1.7.2**. Please check [What's New in 1.7.2](http://wiki.awesomium.net/changelogs/whats-new-1-7-2.html)